# server.ssl.key-store-password is not readable

Tags: java, spring, ssl

I try to add https support to my spring web service.

In my application.properties I have added :

```
server.ssl.key-store: tomcat.keystore
server.ssl.key-store-password: xxxxxx
server.ssl.key-password: XXXXX
```

I then get this error message when starting the service:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource
    [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]:
    Initialization of bean failed;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties':
    Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException:
    Invalid property 'ssl[key-store-password]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties]:
    Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'ssl[key-store-password]';
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException:
    Invalid property 'ssl[key-store-password]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties]:
    Bean property 'ssl[key-store-password]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method:
    Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Where should I start investigating?

Comment: I have tried both with ":" and "=" but I get the same error reported.

Comment: I can only give a vague guess, that spring converts your application.properties in an unexpected way. Maybe you can find a hint here: [boot-features-external-config.html](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)!